# ejabberd mod_multicast error

Tags: ejabberd, mod-multicast

I am using the mod_multicast(XEP-0033) in ejabberd, But I get the error

> "mod_multicast:handle_info:176 Error when processing IQ stanza:
>   {{case_clause,<<"jabber:iq:roster">>},[{mod_multicast,process_iqreply_result,4,[{file,"src/mod_multicast.erl"},{line,738}]},{mod_multicast,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/mod_multicast.erl"},{line,174}]},{gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,593}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,659}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}".

Who can help me? Thank you first. The JAVA code is

```
MultipleRecipientManager.send( connection, message, list, null, null, null,null,false );
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash actually means your client is broken. It replies to the mod_multicast discovery IQ of support for [XEP-0033](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html) with an IQ in the roster namespace.

Please look at discovery section of the XEP-0033 to help get discovery of extended Stanza addressing in your client right: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html#disco-support